# Using kmeans clustering for timeseries data

Tags: python, time-series, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have a dataframe that represent the evolution of two metrics frequency and recency of each user per week

```
User Week   Frequency   Recency
1     1       10         15
1     2        9         13
1     3       12         11
2     1        5         14
2     2        4         10
2     3        8         8
```

i want to cluster this users using k-means based on two metrics frequency and recency, but i dont know how can use this algorithm with a time series data.

it makes sense if i ignore the column week and consider all the features as features of data points ?
i have seen sources presented  a distance  called dynamic_time_warping distance, but i dont know how to use it in my context?

Comment: This is not a programming question. This is a question about clustering, a mathematical concept.

Comment: Moreover: Before considering what kind of clustering you want to do, you must decide what the points to be clustered in your data actually are. What are they?

Comment: The question seems incomplete. Can you please put some more details like what are the actual points you want to cluster, what points you want to consider to work with.

Comment: @JoyantaJ.Mondal i want to cluster users based on both metrics frequency and recency

Comment: @geekProgramer: In what way would you like a user to be a point in some space? What kind of space is that? Is that space even amenable to k-means?